# XMLHttpRequest is not defined Chrome Extension MV3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I understand XMLHttpRequest doesn't work with service worker (Chrome Extension manifest v3) so I need replacement of it for the following upload functionality. I am not sure how standard fetch how can be used for uploading with events like onreadystatechange and onprogress. Any example of fetch for upload purpose with events would be appreciated

```
var request = self.uploadXHR[index] = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    
};

request.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
    
};

request.open('PUT', url, true);

request.send(blob);
```

Comment: Use the standard [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch).

Comment: @wOxxOm does fetch offer onreadystatechange and onprogress events?

Comment: No, it doesn't but there is a workaround for uploading, which you can find yourself.

Comment: @wOxxOm Any example of it would be appreciated

Comment: Yeah, there should be lots of examples around, it's a popular demand, keep searching.

Comment: https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/607

Comment: @wOxxOm
http://devdoc.net/web/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchObserver.html
Check the browser compatibility for it. Are you sure it works?

Comment: The observer isn't yet implemented. The topic I've linked contains examples of workarounds. You can find more yourself, if you don't like these